# UI Calendar events not displaying

Tags: angularjs, ui-calendar

Im trying to create a calendar but the events are not showing. I was wondering if someone would be able to help me.

Here are the events

```
$scope.events = [
          {title: 'Long Event',start: new Date('Thu Oct 17 2016 10:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)'),end: new Date('Thu Oct 17 2013 17:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)')},
          {id: 999,title: 'Repeating Event',start: new Date('Thu Oct 17 2016 09:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)'),allDay: false},
          {id: 999,title: 'Repeating Event',start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0),allDay: false},
          {title: 'Birthday Party',start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),allDay: false},
          {title: 'Click for Google',start: new Date(y, m, 28),end: new Date(y, m, 29),url: 'http://google.com/'}
        ];
```

Here is the eventSource

```
 $scope.eventSource = {
            url: "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic",
            className: 'gcal-event',           // an option!
            currentTimezone: 'America/Chicago' // an option!
          };
```

This is where I initialize eventsources and push the events.

```
 $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events, $scope.eventSource, $scope.eventsF];
```

Comment: Any errors on the F12 dev tools console?

Comment: I checked and there were none

Comment: Why are you trying to add `$scope.events` into the `$scope.eventSources` array twice?